# apoc.periodic.iterate process dynamic list using Spring/Java

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm, neo4j-apoc

1. I want to pass the list that needs to be iterated and create nodes and relationships out of it.
2. I am using Apoc.periodic.iterate now because previously i have tried with unwind which caused deadlock due to parallel execution.
3. Help me to fix the current code section.
4. I am processing more than 900k data in chunks. Which i will read it from kafka topics.

   Current Code Section:
         
            `@Query("CALL apoc.periodic.iterate("+"\""
                + " UNWIND $items as item return item\" ,"
                + "\"MERGE (src:Item {name: item.name}) "
                + " ON CREATE SET src.name = item.name, "
                + " src.updateDate = {processDate} "
                + "MERGE (dest:ItemDet {upc: item.upc}) "
                + " ON CREATE SET dest.upc = item.upc, "
                + "   dest.creationDate = {processDate} " )\", 
               {batchSize:1000, parallel:false,iterateList:true,params:{items:{items}}})")
            Result mergeItems(@Param("items") List<?> items,
                              @Param("processDate") String processDate);`

   Previous code Section:

   `@Query("UNWIND {items} as item MERGE(src:Item {name: item.name}) "
                + " ON CREATE SET src.name = item.name, "
                + " src.updateDate = {processDate} "
                + "MERGE (dest:ItemDet {upc: item.upc}) "
                + " ON CREATE SET dest.upc = item.upc, "
                + "   dest.creationDate = {processDate} ")
   Result mergeItems(@Param("items") List<?> items,
                   @Param("processDate") String processDate);`

ERROR LOG

```
ERROR Unexpected error detected in bolt session '8c8590fffeb2c45f-000098a4-00000004-54a89d3a07b39611-ca025a5c'. Failed to process a bolt message
org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltConnectionFatality: Failed to process a bolt message
    at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltStateMachine.handleFailure(BoltStateMachine.java:742)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltStateMachine.handleFailure(BoltStateMachine.java:728)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltStateMachine.access$500(BoltStateMachine.java:62)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltStateMachine$State$1.init(BoltStateMachine.java:435)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltStateMachine.init(BoltStateMachine.java:145)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.messaging.BoltMessageRouter.lambda$onInit$0(BoltMessageRouter.java:70)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.runtime.DefaultBoltConnection.processNextBatch(DefaultBoltConnection.java:195)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.runtime.DefaultBoltConnection.processNextBatch(DefaultBoltConnection.java:143)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.runtime.ExecutorBoltScheduler.executeBatch(ExecutorBoltScheduler.java:170)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.runtime.ExecutorBoltScheduler.lambda$scheduleBatchOrHandleError$2(ExecutorBoltScheduler.java:153)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.neo4j.bolt.security.auth.AuthenticationException: The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.
    at org.neo4j.bolt.security.auth.BasicAuthentication.doAuthenticate(BasicAuthentication.java:78)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.security.auth.BasicAuthentication.authenticate(BasicAuthentication.java:60)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltStateMachineSPI.authenticate(BoltStateMachineSPI.java:93)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltStateMachine$State$1.init(BoltStateMachine.java:412)
    ... 10 more
2019-02-02 02:31:53.511+0000 INFO  starting batching from `UNWIND $ingredientUpcModels as node return node` operation using iteration `MERGE (src:Token {name: node.tokenKey})  ON CREATE SET src.name = node.tokenKey, src.creationDate = {processDate},  src.updateDate = {processDate} MERGE (dest:Item {divUpc: node.divUpc})  ON CREATE SET dest.upc = node.upc,    dest.divNumber = node.division,    dest.divUpc = node.divUpc,    dest.creationDate = {processDate} MERGE (src)-[r:TOKEN_ITEM]->(dest)  ON CREATE SET r.creationDate = {processDate}  SET r.score = node.score, r.updateDate = {processDate} )` in separate thread
2019-02-02 02:31:53.544+0000 WARN  Error during iterate.commit:
2019-02-02 02:31:53.544+0000 WARN  1 times: org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Transaction was marked as successful, but unable to commit transaction so rolled back.
2019-02-02 02:31:53.545+0000 WARN  Error during iterate.execute:
2019-02-02 02:31:53.545+0000 WARN  1 times: Invalid input ')': expected whitespace, comment, '.', node labels, '[', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', "<>", "!=", '<', '>', "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR, ',', LOAD CSV, FROM, INTO, START, MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE, CREATE GRAPH >>, CREATE >> GRAPH, CREATE GRAPH, CREATE, SET, DELETE GRAPHS, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH, CALL, PERSIST, RELOCATE, RETURN, SNAPSHOT, UNION, ';' or end of input (line 1, column 515 (offset: 514))
"UNWIND {_batch} AS _batch WITH _batch.node AS node  MERGE (src:Token {name: node.tokenKey})  ON CREATE SET src.name = node.tokenKey, src.creationDate = {processDate},  src.updateDate = {processDate} MERGE (dest:Item {divUpc: node.divUpc})  ON CREATE SET dest.upc = node.upc,    dest.divNumber = node.division,    dest.divUpc = node.divUpc,    dest.creationDate = {processDate} MERGE (src)-[r:TOKEN_ITEM]->(dest)  ON CREATE SET r.creationDate = {processDate}  SET r.score = node.score, r.updateDate = {processDate} )"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ^
2019-02-02 02:31:53.741+0000 INFO  starting batching from `UNWIND $ingredientUpcModels as node return node` operation using iteration `MERGE (src:Token {name: node.tokenKey})  ON CREATE SET src.name = node.tokenKey, src.creationDate = {processDate},  src.updateDate = {processDate} MERGE (dest:Item {divUpc: node.divUpc})  ON CREATE SET dest.upc = node.upc,    dest.divNumber = node.division,    dest.divUpc = node.divUpc,    dest.creationDate = {processDate} MERGE (src)-[r:TOKEN_ITEM]->(dest)  ON CREATE SET r.creationDate = {processDate}  SET r.score = node.score, r.updateDate = {processDate} )` in separate thread
2019-02-02 02:31:53.752+0000 WARN  Error during iterate.commit:
2019-02-02 02:31:53.752+0000 WARN  1 times: org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Transaction was marked as successful, but unable to commit transaction so rolled back.
2019-02-02 02:31:53.752+0000 WARN  Error during iterate.execute:
2019-02-02 02:31:53.752+0000 WARN  1 times: Invalid input ')': expected whitespace, comment, '.', node labels, '[', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', "<>", "!=", '<', '>', "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR, ',', LOAD CSV, FROM, INTO, START, MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE, CREATE GRAPH >>, CREATE >> GRAPH, CREATE GRAPH, CREATE, SET, DELETE GRAPHS, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH, CALL, PERSIST, RELOCATE, RETURN, SNAPSHOT, UNION, ';' or end of input (line 1, column 515 (offset: 514))
"UNWIND {_batch} AS _batch WITH _batch.node AS node  MERGE (src:Token {name: node.tokenKey})  ON CREATE SET src.name = node.tokenKey, src.creationDate = {processDate},  src.updateDate = {processDate} MERGE (dest:Item {divUpc: node.divUpc})  ON CREATE SET dest.upc = node.upc,    dest.divNumber = node.division,    dest.divUpc = node.divUpc,    dest.creationDate = {processDate} MERGE (src)-[r:TOKEN_ITEM]->(dest)  ON CREATE SET r.creationDate = {processDate}  SET r.score = node.score, r.updateDate = {processDate} )"
```

Comment: attached error log raj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1) Its due to syntax error .I have found the fix.
```

```
 @Query("CALL apoc.periodic.iterate("+"\""
    + " UNWIND $items as item return item\" ,"
    + "\"MERGE (src:Item {name: item.name}) "
    + " ON CREATE SET src.name = item.name, "
    + " src.updateDate = {processDate} "
    + "MERGE (dest:ItemDet {upc: item.upc}) "
    + " ON CREATE SET dest.upc = item.upc, "
    + "   dest.creationDate = {processDate} "\", 
    {batchSize:1000, parallel:false,iterateList:true,params:{items:{items},{processDate:{processDate}}}})")
     Result mergeItems(@Param("items") List<?> items,
       @Param("processDate") String processDate);
</CODE>
```